# Массив имён и jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет, есть что то подобное:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="param[]" />
  <input type="text" name="param[]" />
  <textarea name="param[]"></textarea>
  <textarea name="param[]"></textarea>
  <input type="text" name="param[]" />
  <input type="file" name="param[]" />
</form>
```

Можно как нибудь "дозвониться" к элементам по массиву `name=param[]` через jQuery?

Что то вроде: `$('чёто тут').eq(3).val('MySuperValue');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно так:

```
$('[name="param[]"]').eq(3).val('MySuperValue');
```